# Active/current class on custom menu (Wordpress)

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, nav

i'm currently working on a page using Wordpress and AGMA theme.

The thing is i have my top nav and at one of pages i have custom side menu. The top one works great, adding .current_page_item class on active item, but it doesnt work on side-menu.

[image]

What is the best way to do that?
Thanks for any help possible.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Maybe a fiddle (how the css class looks like, both the nav and side menu html...)

Comment: Both menus are made with wodpress manager "menu" option, so i dont even know how to recreate them in code :<.

Comment: Maybe you should check out the wordpress forums for that specific theme, they are most likely in a better understanding what exactly is happening here.

Comment: If you're wanting it per page, you could add the `is_page()` query, then add the class based on what page you are on.